# the calc package doesn't compute the correct value

Tags: pdftex, packages, calculations

I get an unexpected result using the calc package.
I simply try to multiply the real value '10.01' by the entire value '10000' and to store the result in a counter. But the returned value is not the expected '100100' but '100099' instead.

What have I to do to avoid some mistake with the calc package ?

Here is the very simple used code :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}

\newcounter{r}
\begin{document}
  \setcounter{r}{10000 * \real{10.01}}
  \ther
\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Accuracy with TeX is not really good. There are more accurate implementation of floating point numbers.

Comment: In this case, `\setcounter{r}{10000 * 1001 /100}` gives the right answer, but such tricks may not always be available, depending on the inputs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

TeX uses fixed point binary arithmetic and `calc` uses this arithmetic that can't guarantee great accuracy.

You get a better result using implementations of floating point numbers, for example the one in `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
    
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\roundtointeger}{m}
 {
  \fp_eval:n { round ( #1, 0 ) }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcounter{r}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{r}{\roundtointeger{10000 * 10.01}}

\ther
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this help. I get now the correct result using the fp package.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the egreg answer, i found another package to fix my problem :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fp}

\newcounter{r}
\begin{document}
  \FPeval{\result}{round(10000 * 10.01,0)}
  \setcounter{r}{\result}
  \ther
\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help.